# Are there trade offs between using a geohash vs using a quadkey as a spatial index?

Tags: bing-maps, spatial-index, geohash, quadtree

### QuadKey

Bing Maps uses a quadkey structure for their tiling scheme. Here is an overview of the concept http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.

### GeoHash

A geohash seems to be the more accepted representation in the open source word  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

So what I am wondering is if there are any trade offs between the two when being used as a spatial index. They are both rooted in the quadtree concept and carry it's pros and cons, but are there benefits to using one over the other?

Comment: Also, here's a python implementation of a quadkey  https://github.com/buckheroux/QuadKey.

Answer (score 3):

There are several benefits to geohash over quadkey:

- **cross language support**. geohash has open source implementations in a number of languages (c, java, python, ruby, perl, javascript).  If you need external contributors to connect with your quadtree based data, you gain maximum flexibility with geohash.  If you are using python, there is a pre-built c-extension that helps compute geohash values with greater speed than quadkey.

  - **bug hunting**.  Geohash is widely adopted in the open source community (e.g. ElasticSearch, MongoDB, and others) implement geohash indexes as a form of spatial indexing in their systems.  If you run into something weird with your data, your odds of finding the problem (and solution) are better with geohash.
  - **community**.  You can create URLs that convert a geohash to a visible map via a shareable URL at geohash.org.   For example, here's a URL for [Washington, DC](http://geohash.org/dqcjr6)

Answer (score 1):

Quadtrees are more predictable in that each level spans a square, whereas in geohash representation sometimes squares sometimes rectangles are spanned.

See: [geohash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html#_cell_dimensions_at_the_equator), [quadtree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx)